# How exactly does the Unlockable Pack DLC work?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

The description states the following:

> The Unlockable Pack gives access to all unlockable items, upgrades and bonuses that weren't chosen during normal gameplay. Now you can have it all!

I read the description on [the wiki](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Unlockable_Pack), and I understand that I'll be able to get mission rewards that were previously mutually exclusive to each other, but I'm confused about this part:

> If this DLC is unlocked before playing missions which contain choices, nothing will be unlocked when those missions are played.

I'm currently fairly early in my save (I re-purchased it on PC and am replaying it there), so I haven't yet completed all the missions that have choices. If I get this DLC, does the previous statement mean I won't get *any* rewards? Is this because I'll already have unlocked them with the DLC or will I just not get them at all? I'm assuming the former, but the wording is unclear to me.

Also, does this DLC automatically unlock everything at the beginning, or can you toggle it on and off? Again, as I'm fairly early in the game, I don't quite want to unlock everything yet, but will this DLC do so if I simply purchase it? Basically, I need to know if I should hold off on buying this if I'm not yet done with the game.

Answer (score 4):

When you buy and apply the *Unlockable Pack* DLC, you will get all of the rewards of all of the possible mission choice rewards. So, for example, you will get the lump sum cash bonus AND the percentage cash bonus from the The Ho Boat mission. Missions usually have a static reward with no choice involved. Such missions without optional rewards will not be unlocked automatically via the *Unlockables Pack* DLC.

The optional bonuses are all unlocked and applied once you are past the third mission of the game which involves assaulting the Steelport guard armory for munitions ("We're going to need guns"). This is also when you first exist in Steelport while not bound to a mission, and when you spawn in Shaundi's ex's crib. The unlocks will appear as rewards screens, like upgrades or (post-)mission (completion) rewards, a few seconds after you've spawned.

There is no choice; they are involuntarily applied at that point. The biggest downside to this is being forced to use a City Takeover. If you want it to have the least impact, I recommend choosing Arapice Island (in the mid-west).

Update: Well, I finally got around to recording the footage.

This is me unlocking every SR3 DLC. The unlockables pack should be the rewards regarding the gangs. It is also responsible for me having to use a City Takeover. Note that this occurs (at any point) after the third mission.